# Fabric React: GroupedList: Possible to avoid multiple row selection?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I have been trying to use GroupedList within Fabric-React. I need to avoid multiple row selection if that can be helped. i.e. if I select a row, previously selected row should get de-selected.

Here's the groupedlist: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/groupedlist

Comment: You need to be specific when asking questions. It is best when you describe your problem and then present your code solution and the error messages you find. It is best not to make people link to different site. Instead the question must be reproducible by others given enough info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}`

```
          <SelectionZone selection={this._selection} selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}>
            <GroupedList
              items={this._items}
              onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}
              selection={this._selection}
              selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
              groups={this._groups}
              compact={isCompactMode}
            />
          </SelectionZone>
```

Where the selectionMode on `<GroupedList />` says only one selection per group and the selctionMode on `<SelectionZone />` says only one selection for all groups.

Comment: Thanks @Lumpenstein ! This worked for me.  oaxacamatt, thanks for the advice. I'll try and make my questions as specific as possible.

Comment: Hi @lumpenstein ! I have another question on a grouped list. Say I want to add a drop-down/labels/input elements to group-headers in a grouped list. Is it possible to add the same as of today ?

Comment: Look at the second example called `GroupedList example with custom header and footer` of the [groupedList documentaton](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/groupedlist).

Comment: Thanks @lumpenstien ! I replaced the <groupHeader> element with my own div. Was able to create custom-elements in group header, but the tree structure was lost. I need the tree structure too, so I added the new divs inside <GroupHeader></GroupHeader>. However, I got the tree structure back without my divs being honored.